# Angular: Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I am upgrading my project from Angular v5 to Angular v6, but am getting the following error:

> Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.

Below is a look at my current **package.json**

```
{
      "name": "default",
      "author": "",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "license": "MIT",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "testbuild": "ng build --environment=test",
        "preprodbuild": "ng build --environment=preprod",
        "build": "ng build --prod",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "postinstall": "npm run tsformat",
        "tsformat": "tsfmt -r"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^6.1.9",
        "@angular/common": "^6.1.9",
        "@angular/core": "^6.1.9",
        "@angular/forms": "^6.1.9",
        "@angular/http": "^6.1.9",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.9",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.9",
        "@angular/router": "^6.1.9",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.2.2",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.3.10",
        "angular2-csv": "^0.2.9",
        "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
        "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
        "core-js": "^2.5.7",
        "enhanced-resolve": "^4.1.0",
        "express": "^4.16.3",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "ng-recaptcha": "^4.0.0",
        "ngx-moment": "^3.1.0",
        "ngx-restangular": "^3.0.0",
        "ngx-spinner": "^6.1.2",
        "ngx-store": "^2.0.0",
        "npm": "^6.4.1",
        "oauth": "^0.9.15",
        "primeng": "^6.1.4",
        "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
        "to": "^0.2.9",
        "typescript-formatter": "^7.2.2",
        "update": "^0.7.4",
        "xlsx": "^0.14.0",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.8.4",
        "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.9",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.9",
        "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.9",
        "@ng-idle/core": "^6.0.0-beta.3",
        "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^6.0.0-beta.3",
        "express": "^4.16.3",
        "typescript": "~2.9.2"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you follow the [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/)? Also did you check to see if you have an `angular.json` file on your file system now? It should be at the same level as your `package.json` file. Angular v5 uses `angular-cli.json` which was replaced with `angular.json` in v6.

Comment: IIRC Angular5 uses `.angular.json`... But that's not the point. Just follow update guide as was suggested.